# Can I disable sidescrolling altogether?

Tags: scrolling, conceal

If some characters are concealed in a line, so that the effectively the entire line is visible, and `nowrap` is set, moving to the end of the line can cause Vim to scroll if the actual line length is greater than what can be displayed. Lines without concealed characters aren't affected.

For example:

[image]

The terminal is 95 characters wide. The current line is 78 characters long, and since it has nothing concealed, it doesn't scroll. The line above does have concealed characters, and it scrolls, leaving a jagged edge:

[image]

The displayed part of both lines fit comfortably in 95 characters. Concealed characters are completely hidden (`set concealcursor=nvic conceallevel=3`).

Can I tell Vim to not scroll in such cases?

---

Using `set sidescrolloff=0` had no effect.

In this case, I'm viewing manpages, and I *know* that the visible length will never be more than the display area. In this case, just disabling sidescrolling altogether would be fine.

Comment: Very related: [How to disable horizontal scrolling?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2883/51) ... possible duplicate?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker if I read that right, there's no way to disable it?

Comment: Not as far as I − or apparently anyone else − was able to figure out... :-/

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Sigh. Conceal was showing so much promise. I think I'll go back to removing backspaces. :/

Comment: Conceal unfortunately has some quirks, like this one (there are others) ... The implementation is rather hackish :-/